# Centering a image when the application is ran

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this application I made where when you click on the exe a Image Pops up that says *Checking for Updates* and if there isn't any it runs the main codes. But every time I click on it the image ends up somewhere random in the screen, is there a way to center the image in the screen to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Is the image on a form, and it's actually the form that is appearing at different positions on the screen?  If so it's because the form's `StartPosition` property is set to `WindowsDefaultLocation`.  You can set it to `CenterScreen`.

Comment: Which technology are you using ?  Winforms or WPF ? And also, you should post some code to les us help you (i.e. your popup's code and invokation)

Comment: do you have any onClick() methods behind the image?

Comment: I'm just using a normal windows form, No type of onClick() methods in it, it does an update check automatically, its just the image keep popping up in random positions each time you click on it.

Comment: It's not an "image that's popping up". It's a *form you're creating that displays an image*, and "How do I center a form on-screen?" would be a much clearer question.

Answer (score 1):

If your VS project type is a Windows Form Application you can just view the forms designer and set the **StartPosition** to **CenterScreen** or **CenterParent**

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 WinForms (+ I assume) supports a splash screen. Add a form (a splash screen template is available) and in the Project properties select the new form. The Splash Screen appears center screen.

The splash screen will display until your startup form exits the Load event - or you can just end the app if you don't have anything more to do. Not sure what the code would be for a console app.